# How to use cache in proxy and filter by content in Centos 7.3 and Freebsd

Tags: centos, freebsd, proxy, cache, filter

I have a **proxy server** running well, but I would like to know how to **filter by content**, not only a webpage, and then how to use **cache**.

I am not sure if to use the cache I have to uncomment only a line in which is set the file where cache will be saved. With content I know nothing.